# Comparing the value of readline() to a string

Tags: java, string, sockets, inputstream

I am reading the `inputstream` using `readline()` method and then trying to compare it.

The code is as follows:

```
//socket is defined before this
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();

br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

Line = br.readLine();

    if (Line  == "hey") {
        Log.d("watsapp client tag", "message pushed !!");
        Log.d("watsapp client tag", "" + Line);


    }
   else {

        Log.d("watsapp client tag", "message not pushed");
        Log.d("watsapp client tag", "" + Line);

    }
```

The above code always executes the else part. although first value of the input stream is "hey" and second is not. So I am expecting in the logcat "message pushed !!" and "message not pushed" instead I get both "message not pushed"

```
05-31 14:46:14.309    6138-6151/? D/watsapp client tag﹕ message not pushed
05-31 14:46:14.309    6138-6151/? D/watsapp client tag﹕ hey
05-31 14:46:14.339    6138-6151/? D/watsapp client tag﹕ message not pushed
05-31 14:46:14.339    6138-6151/? D/watsapp client tag﹕ <Messageadded:1112/>
```

Please can tell what is going wrong at line `if (Line  == "hey")`. Thanks!

Comment: Use `equals` when comparing Strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to compare `String` using `equals()` method. The `==` operator here check the references. Compare `String` (and other reference type variables) like this -

```
String firstString = "someValue";
String secondString = "someValue";

if(firstString.equals(secondString)){
   System.out.println("both string are equals"); 
}else{
   System.out.println("not equals"); 
}
```

**Update:** Sometimes we compare a variable of type `String` to a `String` literal or constant. Then it's better to perform the check like this -

```
String str1 = "aString";
String str2 = null;
System.out.println( "aString".equals(str1) ); //true;
System.out.println( "aString".equals(str2) ); //false;
```

The advantage of comparing like this you never get `NullPointerException` in the second case.

Comment: I tried that then it gives me NPE